# English grammar Genitive case

Tags: possessives

Please help me, I am confused.

As you know some times we can 'of' in a noun phrase by reversing the nouns order eg.

a train of goods => a goods train

If I want to mention a definite  'goods train' I can say

the goods train

now, the question, if I need to mention a  a particular train carring a  a particular goods

Do I have to say "the train of the goods"? or I can say "the goods trains"

thanks a lot

Comment: You can say a coal train, a cement train, a car train, a newspaper train - is that the sort of thing you are wondering about?

Comment: Your question and examples have nothing to do with the genitive case. "goods train" is a noun phrase with "train" as head and the plural noun "goods" as modifier. And "train of goods" is not genitive, and in any case is infelicitous.

Comment: This seems to be about the use of articles as determiners. In other words, **the** is more specific while **a** is more generic.